# Regular expression in velocity template not working

Tags: regex, velocity

i am using following regular expression to check if string starts with `http(s)` or `www.`

```
#if($message.matches(".*(https?://|www\t.).*"))
```

this condition is true if string starts with `http` or `https` but fails on `www.`

Can any one kindly tell me what i am doing wrong.

The above condition is true for

```
http://www.google.com
https://education.10gen.com
http://www.youtube.com
```

and fails for

```
www.google.com
www.youtube.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(https?://|www\t.)`

You have a `t` in here that is a mistake.

`(https?://|www\.)`

If you are using this in a string type where backslashes indicate escaping, you have to double the backslash so it is escaped to one backslash by the time the regex engine reads it:

`(https?://|www\\.)`

Comment: thanks for response, when i remove the "t", i get the error stating "Lexical error: org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 43, column 48.  Encountered: "." (46), after : "\".*(https?://|www\\""

Comment: @Shahzeb Double up the backslash, since it is in a "" style string.

Comment: Thanks for your precious time, removing the backslash worked. Now my regular expression is "(https?://|www.)" and its working as i wanted.

Comment: @Shahzeb Cool, be sure to upvote/accept the answer if it was good and helpful respectively.

Comment: can you kindly update your answer (by removing both backslashes) so that i will mark it as answer, for later use.

Comment: @Shahzeb The backslashes are necessary. `.` is a metacharacter in regex that means 'match one of anything'. `www.` matches wwwa, wwwb, www# and so on. `www\.` or `www\\.` (depending on context) matches only `www.`